# Using webpack to load react images

Tags: reactjs, image, npm, webpack

i have problem with loading images, when deploying to server.
I don't know a cause, but when npm rendering a images, only few works.

I analysed it:

[image]

If, images load well it's path to (data:image/svg+xml(...)), when i checked code syntax. **advantage_first** and **advantage_second** are similar.

When importing:

```
import adv1 from './img/advantage_first.svg'
import adv2 from './img/advantage_second.svg'
```

And when rendering:

```
        <img src={adv1} />
        <img src={adv2} />
```

It's section, which load images **webpack.config.js**

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|ttf|otf|pdf|ico)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'url-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]&limit=8192'
  }
```

Where i should find problem?

Have a nice day

Comment: Try to increase the limit of image loader(url-loader) from 8192 to 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 { test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|ttf|otf|pdf|ico)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024000' }
```

Comment: It's not resolving the problem.

Comment: I upload to server with 102400. And now i have problem with out of memory.
It's depend on server or something others?

Comment: 1024000 is A Number specifying the maximum size of a file in bytes. If the file is greater than the limit, file-loader is used by default and all query parameters are passed to it.

Comment: If this number too large and you import file large, then file bundle will large and page load slow

Comment: When i using 102400, i get error about allocation and having a memory.

Comment: Could you show me more detail? You can try another number less than 102400

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185728/api-fatal-error-process-out-of-memory

I open other answer for it.